# How do I put a .mov file in flashplayer?

Tags: php, html, css, flash, flash-player

I have a flash player, and up until now, I just link movies from youtube etc...

```
    <record>    
        <movie>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2XH5KrrPw8</movie>
        <title>blah test</title>
        <desc>YOYOYOYOYOYOY</desc>
        <preview>videos/previews/avatar.jpg</preview>
        <imgplaylist>videos/imgplaylist/p1.jpg</imgplaylist>
        <category>Action;Adventure;Sci-Fi; ALL CATEGORIES</category>
        <banner>videos/banners/sony.swf</banner>
        <bannerLink>http://www.flashcomponents.net/author/LambertGroup.html</bannerLink>
    </record>   

</gallerylist>
```

I now have a large .mov file that I want to host on there. Should I make a folder for it and put it on my server and link to it? or is there a better way?

If I do put it in a folder on my site and link to it, do I need to put the .mov extention on the folder or the .mov file inside the folder will take care of that? Sorry, seems like a silly question but I've never dealt with this before

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

simply, flash doesn't support .mov files, it'll need to be converted to an flv or something supported by flash

Comment: This is 100% wrong. http://www.google.com/search?q=mov%20site%3Aflowplayer.org  Flash supports QuickTime .mov files, and certain formats that it can utilize.

Comment: it's not at all, not all .mov's are H264 - and not all flash players are the latest 10.x's

Comment: That's an interesting way of acknowledging one's inaccuracy. :p  P.S.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash#Flash_Audio http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how exactly the file was encoded, it may or may not "just work" with [Flash video player](http://flowplayer.org/)s.  If it wasn't encoded as required, you will indeed need to [transcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcoding).  This can be done easily server-side with [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), and otherwise with any of a handful of FFmpeg frontends ([HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/), [WinFF](http://winff.org/), [ffmpegX](http://homepage.mac.com/major4/)).